# .data() in Jquery always returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, list

I have an array of `li` elements called `$myList`, and I'm trying to compare the most recent item in the list to another value (called `$partType`) to see if they are the same. Specifically, I'm comparing an attribute in each list item called `data-parttype` to `$partType`.

**Here is my code:**

```
var $lastItem = $myList.last(); // getting the most recent list item
var lastPartType = $lastItem.data('parttype'); // getting the data attribute

if (lastPartType != null) { //skip all this if the list is empty
    if (lastPartType == $partType) { // see if the part types are the same
        alert("Last part type: " + lastPartType + ", this part type: " + $partType + ". SAME!");
    } else {
        alert("Last part type: " + lastPartType + ", this part type: " + $partType + ". DIFFERENT!");
    }
}
```

In the actual code, instead of alerts, I have my code send a warning message to the user if the current part type (`$partType`) doesn't match the most recent part type in the list (`lastPartType`). If it matches, it gets added the list and the process repeats. Ultimately, my goal here is to make sure the entire list can only have one part type, by warning the user when they try to add something different from what they've already added.

Here is an example of one of the list items in `$myList`:

```
<li data-parttype="new" data-id="151">1099628-15-53-27<i class="fa fa-check fa-fw text-success"></i></li>
```

**The problem** is that when I pepper alerts throughout the code to see what's happening, it turns out `lastPartType` is always "undefined". I expect that if the list is empty, but even when the list is full of items, it is still "undefined".

Comment: You're using the attribute name `data-type`, so to access it the key should be `"type"`, not `"parttype"`.

Comment: That's actually a mistake in writing out the question... in the real project it is `data-parttype` and `.data('parttype')`. Fixed the question

Comment: Are you trying to get data-id attribute in this line? `var lastPartType = $lastItem.data('parttype');`

Comment: Is the $lastItem  really referring to the last item?

Comment: Need to provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue. You are telling us that code we can't see is not doing what is expected. Without full code context we have no idea why

Comment: Have you tried doint this? `$lastItem.attr('data-parttype');`

Comment: @Lixus that should not be necessary.

Comment: @Lixus I'm actually trying to get data-parttype, not data-id... and yes, I have tried the .attr() method as well

Comment: @NathanR are you sure that `$lastItem.length` is not zero?

Comment: @NawedKhan $lastItem is supposed to be referring to $myList.last(), which is supposed to be the last item in the `$myList` array

Comment: Please confirm with $lastItem.length

Comment: @NawedKhan and Pointy, it says $lastItem.length is 1

Comment: and does the data('id') return the correct value? if not you are definitely not looking at the desired LI

Comment: @NawedKhan It doesn't... Earlier I actually added a regular `id` attribute just to see if I could catch it, and it returned the `id` that belongs to $myList instead ... am I not selecting the list items correctly with $myList.last() ?

Comment: @NathanR  this means you are getting the List and not the List Items (items of the list). How is $myList populated? Is it the list (UL or OL) or the items (LI)?

Comment: @NawedKhan Yes, this was the problem. $myList is a UL called `$('#electrodes')`and I was trying to get the LI items. I solved it by just making a second list that targets `$('#electrodes li')`... is there a better way to get to the LI items without making another list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments apparently $myList is the List and not the list Items. To get the last item do this:

```
var $lastItem = $myList.find('li').last(); // getting the most recent list item
```